# Определить откуда пришел юзер в контроллере в kohana фреймворке?

Tags: php, kohana

У меня есть две ссылки, напр. mysite/web и mysite/application, и есть контроллер subject, который принимает action_index, в котором определяются два массива, но вывести нужен только 1, в зависимости от того, по какому url перешел пользователь, т.е. если он кликнул по mysite/web, то в вид subject должен передаваться массив $webs, если же он кликнул по mysite/application, то естественно и массив будет другой ($apps). Проблема в том что я не знаю как определить в контроллере по какому url юзер перешел. Конечно можно это через стандартные фун-ии легко определить, но может все-таки у kohana есть какие-то свои более простые методы или классы на счет этого дела?

Я использую два роута для этих двух ссылок:

```
Route::set('applications', 'applications(/<url>)', array('url' => '.+'))
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'subject',
            'action'     => 'index',        
    ));

Route::set('web', 'web(/<url>)', array('url' => '.+'))
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'subject',
            'action'     => 'index',        
    ));
```

Тоже тут я так понимаю возможны варианты.

Ну и сам контроллер subject (хотя я думаю это не так уж и существенно):

```
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Subject extends Controller_Base {

public function action_index()
{
    $webs = array();
    $apps = array();

    $app = new Model_Application();
    $apps = $app->get_all();

    $web = new Model_Web();
    $webs = $web->get_all();

    // тут получить эту ссылку, и в зависимости от url (web/application) уже свитчить какой массив передавать

    switch ( ??? ) {

        case "web": $links = $webs; break;
        case "application": $links = $apps; break;

    }

    $subject = View::factory('subject')
                ->set('links',$links);

    $this->template->webs = $webs;
    $this->template->apps = $apps;

    $this->template->content = $subject;

}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1. Красивый.**

Если немного покопаться в:

- /system/classes/kohana/route.php
- /system/classes/kohana/request.php

То можно прийти к такому выводу.

```
$current_route = Request::$current->route();       // объект Route
$current_route_name = Route::name($current_route); // название маршрута
echo $current_route_name;
```

В документации это тоже должно быть, но времени займет больше.

**Вариант 2. Тоже рабочий.**

В маршруте можно прописать свои параметры:

```
/* маршруты */
Route::set('applications', 'applications(/<url>)', array('url' => '.+'))
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'subject',
            'action'     => 'index',        
            'new_param'  => 'applications',
    ));

/* контроллер */
public function action_index()
{
    $new_param = $this->request->param(new_param);
    // что-то еще
}
```

В данном случае этот вариант хуже, но в какой-то иной ситуации может помочь.

Comment: Ага, оно! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: У меня в обоих примерах разный способ получить ``Request``, поэтому, чтобы не запутать, в ``$request`` будет один и тот же объект, если..

    $request = Request::$current; // ..вызван не важно откуда
    $request = $this->request;    // ..вызван из главного контроллера